# I've a math problem about series but can't find a suitable formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

I'm developing a program that requires a mathematical formula. You can see it below:

"1+1.1+1.21+1.331+1.4641+1.6105+1.7715……"

The problem is that I want to find the sum of 100 or 1000 numbers in this sequence.

The sequence is that eveytime the following number is 110% more than the previous.

I've studied about series (sequence) in high school, thought I could solve it using geometric or Arithmetic series but no luck.

If anyone is interested in solving the problem please reply with the formula.

Thank you.

Comment: It is a typical finite geometric series

Comment: You have a geometric progression with $r=1.1$.

Comment: This is a geometric series with common ratio $r=1.1$. Where exactly did you fail with this approach?